# Name resolution won't find my server, but DIG will. Why?

Tags: 18.04, dns

On Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ nmcli dev show | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.71.73.45
IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.10.1.10
IP4.DNS[3]:                             10.10.1.11
```

and

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search int.demarcohome.com demarcohome.com pchem.pro
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

and

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   nick

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and

```
$ dig @10.10.1.10 ipa1.pchem.pro
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> @10.10.1.10 ipa1.pchem.pro
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64107
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: e0b264dbb674673a875433205e64f22cacb2616d8b1969b2 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ipa1.pchem.pro.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ipa1.pchem.pro.     1200    IN  A   10.10.1.10

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
pchem.pro.      86400   IN  NS  ipa1.pchem.pro.
```

then why not

```
$ dig ipa1.pchem.pro

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> ipa1.pchem.pro
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 19340
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ipa1.pchem.pro.            IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Sun Mar 08 09:32:08 EDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43
```

or

```
$ nslookup ipa1.pchem.pro
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find ipa1.pchem.pro: NXDOMAIN
```

???

There's one Ethernet adapter

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:40:00:53 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.71.73.137/24 brd 10.71.73.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute ens33
       valid_lft 220sec preferred_lft 220sec
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe40:53/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

EDIT: Responding to @heynnema comment (and thank you):

```
$ dig @10.71.73.45 ipa1.pchem.pro

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> @10.71.73.45 ipa1.pchem.pro
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 47997
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 0f8732674030db65f517a8c75e652bac26cb9fdab2bcf562 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ipa1.pchem.pro.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
pchem.pro.      3601    IN  SOA dns1.registrar-servers.com. hostmaster.registrar-servers.com. 1582732969 43200 3600 604800 3601

;; Query time: 51 msec
;; SERVER: 10.71.73.45#53(10.71.73.45)
;; WHEN: Sun Mar 08 13:30:20 EDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 144
```

and

```
$ dig @10.71.73.45 ipa1.pchem.pro

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> @10.71.73.45 ipa1.pchem.pro
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 58109
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: e0a674698cf1f2cac83202565e652bfe51d22df0b694ffca (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ipa1.pchem.pro.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
pchem.pro.      3519    IN  SOA dns1.registrar-servers.com. hostmaster.registrar-servers.com. 1582732969 43200 3600 604800 3601

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 10.71.73.45#53(10.71.73.45)
;; WHEN: Sun Mar 08 13:31:42 EDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 144
```

and

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
          DNS Domain: int.demarcohome.com
                      demarcohome.com
                      pchem.pro
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (ens33)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 10.71.73.45
                      10.10.1.10
                      10.10.1.11
          DNS Domain: ~.
                      int.demarcohome.com
                      demarcohome.com
                      pchem.pro
```

Comment: What happens if you `dig @10.71.73.45 ipa1.pchem.pro` or `dig @10.10.1.11 ipa1.pchem.pro`? Edit your question and show me `systemd-resolve --status`.

Comment: Try adding the libnss-resolve package.  That helps with the name resolutions and may be needed for your 10.x.x.x network.

Comment: @ubfan1 I added, observed no effect, so I removed it.

Comment: @heynnema, I ran the commands and updated the question with the command output. Any further thoughts?

Comment: Yes. 1 or 2 of your DNS servers aren't working. You made a slight mistake when doing my dig commands, in that you did the first one twice, and the second one didn't get done. Please see my initial answer and we can troubleshoot further.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @ndemarco  Hello? Status please...

Comment: Hello, and thanks for staying with me. I made a number of changes to my network overall, segregating the 'demarcohome' and 'pchem.pro' networks, then creating a VPN between them. The original configuration is now gone.

Comment: @ndemarco What about the DNS issue? Was my answer correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your DNS servers aren't working.

`dig @10.71.73.45 ipa1.pchem.pro` # this DNS server is not working

`dig @10.10.1.10 ipa1.pchem.pro` # this DNS server is working

`dig @10.10.1.11 ipa1.pchem.pro` # **we accidentally didn't test this DNS server**

Temporarily change your DNS servers to only show 10.10.1.10, retest. Then go and fix the other DNS servers.